# Why does NSlookup return IP address even if the DNS server is fake?

Tags: dns, nslookup

Originally asked in a newsgroup, full log:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/microsoft.public.windowsxp.general/Ll32NWComwY

[image]

The snapshot shows the DNS answer is truly returned by the fake server.

Comment: Welcome to superuser. Offsite resources often go stale - google is pretty notorious for killing off services. One of our goals is to build a knowledge base. As such could you edit the question so its self contained?

Comment: I've posted your screenshot for you in your post. However - we do expect questions to be self contained - your question would be useless for others in the same situation should your google group or newsgroup link get moved or lost. You might want to edit in essential details of your question so folks would have an easier time of finding what they need - both to answer, and when faced with the same question

Comment: Isn't it a known fact that ISPs (or you know what) in China do MITM to DNS queries? Who knows when will the DNAT be triggered. (And certainly there will not be the slightest problem for them to spoof the source address for the fake when it replies.)

Comment: Thank you Journeyman Geek for doing it for me. It's more readable now.

Comment: Tom Yan: I kinds of know but don't expect it activated by default on all queries.

Comment: I am sorry to have not click "accept" for so long (I am still new to this site). This is an evidence that all DNS requests are hijacked in China.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's nothing "indeed" about it. If your ISP wish to perform MITM (Man-in-the-middle) attack on DNS queries, it is very easy for it redirect the queries to another destination without letting you know (at least not just based on the reply's source IP address).

Here's a proof-of-concept. The following are the firewall rules of a host in my LAN:

```
*nat

-A PREROUTING -p udp --dport 53 -m limit --limit 20/minute -j ACCEPT
-A PREROUTING -p udp --dport 53 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.1.1
-A POSTROUTING -p udp --dport 53 -j SNAT --to-source 192.168.1.110

COMMIT
```

The rules basically means if there are more than a certain number of DNS queries on average, redirect the queries to a specific host (in this case it's just a "normal" DNS forwarder/server, as in it does not fake results itself); otherwise, accept it (i.e. "route" it "as-is").

The last rule causes the replies to be routed back to it first (by masquerading the source as itself), so that the firewall can perform "reverse NAT" to the replies' source with the original destination (and the replies' destination with the original source) that it has kept track of.

And here's the result when I make DNS queries on another host in the LAN with the "man in the middle" host as gateway to the non-existent DNS server:

```
[tom@archlinux ~]$ ssh 192.168.1.143
Last login: Fri Oct 25 14:32:11 2019 from 192.168.1.110
[tom@alarm ~]$ ip r get 200.100.200.100
200.100.200.100 via 192.168.1.110 dev eth0 src 192.168.1.143 uid 1000 
    cache 
[tom@alarm ~]$ while true; do timeout 1 nslookup www.google.com 200.100.200.100; if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then sleep 5; else echo "timeout!"; fi; done

timeout!

timeout!

timeout!

timeout!

timeout!

timeout!

timeout!
Server:     200.100.200.100
Address:    200.100.200.100#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   www.google.com
Address: 172.217.26.132
Name:   www.google.com
Address: 2404:6800:4005:805::2004


timeout!

timeout!
Server:     200.100.200.100
Address:    200.100.200.100#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   www.google.com
Address: 172.217.26.132
Name:   www.google.com
Address: 2404:6800:4005:805::2004


timeout!

timeout!

timeout!
Server:     200.100.200.100
Address:    200.100.200.100#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   www.google.com
Address: 172.217.26.132
Name:   www.google.com
Address: 2404:6800:4005:805::2004

^C
```

Comment: DNS works over UDP **AND** TCP (and now even on TLS, HTTPS, and soon QUIC), so firewall rules just over UDP will not match all traffic.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek All I'm trying to say is, whether a destination "exists" (and when it exists and when it does not) can be entirely "relative" to your ISP/gateway. Neither is the OP asking for a solution for anything but trying to find out why something could happen. (I didn't even say it is exactly his case, but a proof-of-concept of a possibility.)

Comment: @PatrickMevzek Besides, the screenshot clearly tells us it's traffics through port 53 that is in question. While it is unclear whether Wireshark was capturing TCP/UDP/both, it doesn't mean that the rules cannot be added to match TCP 53 traffics as well.

Comment: If ISP is doing sneaky things like this, can I tell if  the answer is normal or fake, when I am using normal DNS service like 8.8.8.8?

Comment: @LuWei To tell if an answer is fake? I guess so, base of different facts / comparison or so. What you cannot tell is whether 8.8.8.8 is always the real 8.8.8.8, as you may be reaching it sometimes but not other times. You may even be selectively (further) forwarded on DNS level.

Comment: It is important to stop conveying the idea that DNS is UDP only. Any example that shows that mislead people. And such misconceptions create huge problems in the past we still have to pay today.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek No one is conveying the idea here. An example that doesn't cover all cases (if it does maybe it isn't even an example anymore) doesn't mean that it conveys the idea that those cases don't exist.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek Did you try to convey that dnscrypt doesn't exist? At least I didn't heard its name from you.

Comment: The fact that you are saying you show the rules on your LAN (which rules apply only to a subset of DNS as they care only about UDP) and then don't understand why I say DNS is not just over UDP I think is the core of the problem but seeing that you do not want to agree on that I will not beat that path further.  Throwing other unrelated points to try covering that fact will not help.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek I have no idea what I'm "covering" or what you want me to agree on or even what changes you want me to make exactly to my answer. No one has ever denied that DNS can be done over TCP. When I say the rules are on a host, it doesn't even mean that they are used on daily basis, but specifically written to show that "something could happen if your ISP does similar things". How exactly does that have anything to do with whether DNS can be done TCP? All I see here is that you learnt a fact and you thought you are a messenger of god or something and everybody is ignorant.